# phpseclib references to $this->bitmask should be $this->bitmap?

Tags: phpseclib

Shouldn't references to $this->bitmask in fact be $this->bitmap?  Noticed in the last download of phpseclib that there are a couple references to $this->bitmask which is not defined at the beginning of the class.  We use $this->bitmap for disconnect detection and noticed it stopped functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed in the new-as-of-today 0.3.6 release. It was fixed in git three months ago whereas the 0.3.5 release was released 9 months ago.

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/pull/167

Also, for bug reports / code improvements you'd probably be better off posting in the github.com project than on stackoverflow.